# Funcionamiento incorrecto de un contador de caracteres dentro de strings en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, algoritmos, diccionarios

Supongamos que tengo la siguiente oración:

```
oracion = 'Mi perro bonito come todas las noches'
```

Y quiero crear una función que cuente la ocurrencia de cada caracter dentro de ella. Con ese fin, importamos string y creamos un alfabeto que sea nuestra referencia:

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_letters
```

La función que hice para el contador de palabras es:

```
def contador(str):
    count= {}
    for letter in str:
        if letter in alphabet:
            if letter in count.keys():
                count[letter]+=1
        else:
                count[letter]=1
    return count
```

Cuando corro

```
contador(oracion)
```

Obtengo siempre esta salida:

```
Out[1]: {' ': 1}
```

Es decir, no hay ningún diccionario que registre la frecuencia de cada letra dentro de la oración. ¿Podrían indicarme cuál es la fuente del error? Honestamente mis conocimientos aún no me dan para hallar en qué me estoy equivocando, ya que creo que el razonamiento detrás de la función es el correcto.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en el nivel de identación del else. En la respuesta de Antonio se corrige pero no se explica la causa. Hay que recordar siempre que los bloques de código en Python son definidos por los niveles de identación.Tal y como está el código, la lógica es la siguiente:

1. Si la letra está en `alphabet` se comprueba si ya esta en el diccionario. Si lo está se suma uno al valor. **Si la clave no esta en el diccionario no se hace nada.**
2. Si la letra no esta en `alphabet` se usa el `else` y se añade la clave al diccionario. Esto causa que solo los caracteres no presentes en `alphabet` no son agregados al diccionario, en este caso el espacio.

Se debe añadir un nivel de identación al `else` para que esté al mismo nivel del `if letter in count.keys():`, de forma que si este no se cumple se ejecute su contenido y se añada la clave.

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_letters

def contador(str_):
    count= {}
    for letter in str_:
        if letter in alphabet:
            if letter in count.keys():
               count[letter] += 1

       #else  <<< A este nivel está en tu código, y debe ser:
            else:
                count[letter] = 1

    return count
```

Ten en cuenta que **no cuentas mayúsculas, la "ñ", las vocales acentuadas ni "ü"**.

Por otro lado, para contar apariciones en un iterable `collections.Counter` ofrece una solución simple y mucho más eficiente. Esto nos retorna un diccionario contando todos los caracteres (no solo letras), podemos filtrarlo si lo deseamos sin problemas:

```
from collections import  Counter
import string

alphabet = set(string.ascii_letters + ("áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑÜü"))
def contador(str_):
    count = Counter(oracion)
    return {key: count[key] for key in alphabet & count.keys()}

oracion = 'Cigüeña, camión, 123'
print(contador(oracion))
```

**Salida:**

```
{'n': 1, 'i': 2, 'C': 1, 'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'e': 1, 'm': 1, 'ó': 1, 'ü': 1, 'y': 1, 'g': 1, 'ñ': 1}
```

Se diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Si se desea contar ambos casos en uno no también es posible.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas:
Tu script está **casi** correcto porque a mí me ha funcionado. Te le escribo aquí:
    import string
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters

```
oracion = 'Mi perro bonito come todas las noches'

def contador(str):
    count= {}
    for letter in str:
        if letter in alphabet:
            if letter in count.keys():
                count[letter]+=1
            else:
                count[letter]=1
    return count

print(contador(oracion))
```

A mí así me ha funcionado correctamente. Me ha mostrado en pantalla una array asociativa de letra y sus repeticiones.

Te faltaba usar la **función print()**.
Lo he probrado en un editor que tengo en el móvil y ha funcionado correctamente

Comment: Esto es raro: copié y pegue tu código (que es exactamente el mismo que puse inicialmente) y funcionó correctamente... ¿Alguna idea del por qué este fallo?

Comment: El que pegaste en la web inicialmente, no tiene la función print(contador(oracion)). Podría ser por la codificación de tu editor, que estuviese cambiada y añada caracteres raros (ocurre bastantes veces con el Notepad++).

Comment: @FJSevilla tienes toda la razón. No me había fijado en la identación del else. Lo había dado por supuesto que estaba bien. Gracias por tu aclaración.